# Skipping through parts of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array that I have condensed down quite a bit from the input data.  I am typing out a long example of it, because I think that will help with the explanation of what I need to do later.  (I am not typing out all the html code, but it displays what I need, so no problems there).

```
storyArray=["#C1",
"String of HTML Code that displays first message",
"String of HTML Code that displays second message",
"#D1",
"String of HTML Code that displays two buttons, B1A & B1B",
"#B1A",
"String of HTML Code that displays if button B1A is clicked",
"#>C2",
"#B1B",
"String of HTML Code that displays if button B1B is clicked",
"#>C2",
"#C2", 
"String of HTML Code that displays third message",
"#D2",
"String of HTML Code that displays two buttons, B2A & B2B",
"#B2A",
"String of HTML Code that displays if button B2A is clicked",
"#>C3",
"#B2B",
"String of HTML Code that displays if button B2B is clicked",
"#>C3",
"#C3",
"Final string of HTML Code"]
```

The array elements like #>C2 and #>C3 are meant to denote "jump to the element that follows #C2 and #C3, respectively.

The array elements like #C1, #C2, #C3 are markers that I want to jump to (see above).

The array element #D1 is to denote that if you click A when the buttons appear, you will jump to the element after #B1A and if you click B then you will jump to the element after #B1B.

So, if the user clicks button A in #D1 and button B in #D2 they should see:

"String of HTML Code that displays first message"

"String of HTML Code that displays second message"

"String of HTML Code that displays two buttons, B1A & B1B"

"String of HTML Code that displays if button B1A is clicked"

"String of HTML Code that displays third message"

"String of HTML Code that displays two buttons, B2A & B2B"

"String of HTML Code that displays if button B2B is clicked"

"Final string of HTML Code"

Unfortunately I can't seem to wrap my head around the if/then logic I would need while looping through this.  Any suggestions appreciated.  I am fully open to using jQuery or similar if needed.

Comment: Do you have to store your data like this? It seems like you could accomplish this easier if you stored your data in an object instead of an array.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. If they click "button A in #D1" how is it supposed to display "first message"? That should only be displayed when they click on #C1 right?

Comment: @Entity:  What I meant is when they eventually choose A after Buttonset D1 is displayed...  Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1563247 But Button A in buttonset D1 would take them to `#B1A` correct? And there are no jump markers to `#C1`, so why would "first message" be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you give is inconsistent, but I wrote a snippet based on my best understanding of your code.

```
function clicked() {
    var idString = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
    for(var i = storyArray.indexOf(idString); i < storyArray.length; i++) {
        var element = storyArray[i];
        if(element.charAt(0) == '#') {
            if(element.charAt(1) == '>') { // it's a goto
                i = storyArray.indexOf("#"+element.substring(2))+1;
            }
            else { // it's a label, so skip
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            displayElement(element); // element is the string to display
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fy13gzbj/2/

It uses very simple logic. Basically it executes the array as if it were a script, from top to bottom. It enters the array at the ID of the clicked button e.g. `#B2B`. It continues down the array until it reaches a goto command (`#>`) or the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks for that!  As soon as I saw you were doing an element at .charAt and then doing a indexOf() method, it all seemed so clear.

Thanks very much!

Comment: @user1563247 Alright, glad I could help! Sorry if I seemed hostile, I just didn't understand. Even if I had the wrong solution hopefully now you have the tools to get you started.

Comment: Didn't seem hostile at all - The problem with trying to explain things like this is that by the time I get through the full explanation you're left with a wall of text for a problem you solved so quickly.

Implementation is done, and it works perfectly, btw.